# как из пользователя телеграм бота создать объект класса python?

Tags: python, ооп, telebot

Мне нужно чтобы когда человек пишет команду создавался объект с его именем или айди. У меня есть класс, но я не могу понять как мне создать объект в ходе выполнения программы, когда человек даёт команду боту.

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, name = None, job = "No job", age = 0, card_first = None):
        self.name = name
        self.job = job
        self.age = age
        jobs.remove(job)
        self.card_first = card_first

    def info(self):
        return str(self.age) + " " + self.job + "\nКарточка №1: " + self.card_first

@bot.message_handler(commands=['enjoy'])
def enjoy(message):
    Player(f"{message.from_user.first_name + message.from_user.last_name}", jobs[random.randint(0, len(jobs)-1)], random.randint(18, 70), cards[random.randint(0, len(cards)-1)])
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id , Player.info())
```

Код не полный, но думаю этого достаточно чтобы понять что мне нужно.

Comment: Используйте либо словарь, либо базу данных sqlite3

Answer (score 0):

Нужно просто присвоить создаваемый объект переменной:

```
player_object = Player(f"{message.from_user.first_name + message.from_user.last_name}", jobs[random.randint(0, len(jobs)-1)], random.randint(18, 70), cards[random.randint(0, len(cards)-1)])
bot.send_message(message.from_user.id , player_object.info())
```